# TYPO3 Extbase: Access to external data sources (external web service)

Tags: typo3, extbase

the TYPO3 documentation here https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/6-Persistence/4-use-foreign-data-sources.html says, it is possible to use external data sources for extbase objects: "These foreign data sources could be tables from the same TYPO3 database or a web service."

The used data mapper allows at least to map objects to any table within the same MySQL database.

I am interested in this "or a web service" part. How to configure the data/property mapper to fetch and store an extbase model from an external web service (e.g. REST)?

Is it already possible with TYPO3 core? If not, does anyone know an extension which such capabillities?

Comment: May svconnector family can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at very old documentation there. Although this is still valid to learn Extbase concepts, I would not recommend the ExtbaseFluidBook for hardcore-details any more. I suppose the claim you quote reflects more of a wish or a slight possibility, not a reality. I am not aware of anybody having gone that route yet.

If I wanted to make an external source look "Extbasey", I would implement a repository and models but just use own logic to select and persist.

Side note: Typo3 v8 integrated doctrine, but only working with records, not objects (-dbal, not -orm): https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Database/Introduction/Index.html - this is used more and more in the core and in extensions. It might be feasible to include doctrine-orm and a doctrine-REST-backend like https://packagist.org/packages/circle/doctrine-rest-driver.

Comment: Did I say Thank You already? :-) Thank you.